# Android scheduled task

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing an Economy application.

In this app I'm adding periodical expenses, and they can be every *x* days or every month. My problem is: how can I apply it?

For example if someone has every 4 of month pay 200€. My problem is how can I add programmatically every 4 of every months this payment? Because if someone doesn't log in on 4 and he logs in on 5, I lost this day, and I can't even add a "notification" to the user saying the payment has been saved.

How can I achieve it?

thanks all and sorry for my not perfect english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can detect the time once your app is installed on a device, save the time in shared preferences 
then you can use alarm manager take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: I will check alarm manager thanks! (btw link not working :) )

Comment: So the alarm manager can perform some code upon reached the scheduled time? nice thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Trigger in background.

Or In front end services can be used.